# SQL to reduce number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, numbers, rows

I have a table with date,hour,min and different objects columns. I am trying to sum(col x) and aggregate it at hour level to reduce number of rows.

```
select count(*) from table where date=xxxx
```

will fetch 19022640 rows, so if I try

```
select count(*) from table where date=xxxx
```

and

```
select sum(col x) from table group by date,hour
```

This does not seem to work. Please help.

Comment: Group by the date and hour columns, *then* use SUM or COUNT. What *doesn't seem to work*?

Comment: Do you mean you have different columns for the date/time parts? That's not a very good idea.

Comment: you need to add the columns date and hour in the select if you use group by

Comment: @jarlh in this case it makes the query trivial, which raises the question - what is the problem with the third query? (assuming the OP didn't actually write `col x`)

Comment: But when comparing dates it will be a mess...

Comment: What does *"This does not seem to work"* mean? You get an error message? You get the wrong values? You crash the server?

Comment: I have 3 columns for datetime - date,hour,min

Comment: If I do select count(*) from table for a particular date - I get 19022640 rows

Comment: I need to reduce the number of rows. So I am trying to sum(col x) and group by hour (This should aggregate min values to hour). Hence the number of rows should reduce... but it doesn not

Answer (score 0):

```
select date,hour, sum(col x) from table group by date,hour
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a description regarding your code and how it solves the OP's issue. Thanks!

Comment: you need to add columns in select if you want to reduce the records. as @Rupa SS wants. grouping two columns will reduce the data as common fields will be in OP only.